# phpmyadmin installation issue

Tags: software-installation

I am having trouble installing phpmyadmin on the raspberry pi zero. The raspberry pi is connected to a Windows 10 laptop with SSH using putty and the internet connection is bridge from my laptop.

At this moment I have installed apache2, php, and mysql but when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

It never connects, it's stuck in 0%, and somehow it causes an error with my wifi and I am unable to connect to the internet from both my raspberrypi and computer.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 2.0A - 2.5A power source?

Comment: im not sure if the power source matter because, it does not bother me if i try to install other thing like apache, only when i try to install phpmyadmin is when i get the error,

Comment: It does matter. The more CPU it takes the more power it needs. Minimum of Current: 2. And maximum 2.5. Should do the trick. Have a look at your power source and get back to me. Okay?